# In my unit test for equality, why does one pointer point to a memory slot rather than the item in memory?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

So I am running a unit test:

```
ASSERT_EQ(mifid_trade_report.contingent_transaction_flag, "CONT");
```

There is a lot more to the above, but I've cut the rest out as it points to many classes and files.

Here is the error message that I get back when running the test:

```
/home/.../test_protocol.cpp:2075: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  mifid_trade_report.contingent_transaction_flag
    Which is: 
  "CONT"
    Which is: 0x563717b6bffe
```

Two questions:

1. Am I right in understanding that the above error message is saying `mifid_trade_report.contingent_transaction_flag` is pointing to `CONT`, while the `CONT` is pointing to the memory slot `0x563717b6bffe`?
2. If 1. is right, why is it pointing to a memory slot rather than the object?

I've copied the pattern for other unit tests exactly the same, but the others don't have the same issue.

Comment: What is the type of `mifid_trade_report.contingent_transaction_flag`?

Comment: You are comparing a pointer to a string literal ("CONT") to a pointer in your struct. You are not comparing strings for equality. This is why it is better in C++ to model your strings as std::string or std::string_view. The compare operators of those will compare the content of the string, not the addresses of a string.

Comment: `name="contingent_transaction_flag" type="string4"/>`. 

I believe it is a string of length 4.

Comment: Is your `contingent_transaction_flag` by any chance a `const char*` ?

Comment: Even if `mifid_trade_report.contingent_transaction_flag` just happens to be a string literal  `"CONT"`, there is no guarantee that `mifid_trade_report.contingent_transaction_flag` is at the same address as `"CONT"` if constant string pooling is off when you built the application.

Comment: `char contingent_transaction_flag[4];`

Comment: @kfsopdf -- `char contingent_transaction_flag[4];` -- This is wrong, as `"CONT"` has 5 characters, which includes the terminating null.

Comment: fun fact, in C++, `"true" == "true"` can be `true` or `false`: https://godbolt.org/z/3hWoszEjz

Comment: Beware, some test frameworks may accept raw strings comparisons (and use `strcmp` under the hood), but you should make sure that yours does. If it just uses plain equality you are almost sure that the result will be false... To better answer your question, the output let me think that `contingent_transaction_flag` only contains non printable charactters (or nothing) before the first null, and that your test framework is not good with string literals like `"CONT"`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ASSERT_STREQ(ptr1,ptr2)`](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html#EXPECT_STREQ) is what you need. It helps to compare the *nul-terminated* C style string content. `ASSERT_EQ` will check for pointer itself since a `char*` just points to the start of a C string.

There are other ways. By setting the nul-terminated string into a container with `==` overloaded. Eg: `std::string` and `std::string_view`

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e4Gx3bEbd)

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>
#include <fmt/format.h>

TEST(Foo,Bar){

    const char* cstring = "foo";
    ASSERT_STREQ(cstring, "foo");
    ASSERT_EQ(std::string(cstring), "foo");
    ASSERT_EQ(std::string_view(cstring), "foo");
}
```

Also [googletest official documentation](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html#EXPECT_EQ) does lead you to `*_STREQ` apis

Quote:

> #### EXPECT_EQ
>
> EXPECT_EQ(val1,val2)
> ASSERT_EQ(val1,val2)
>
> Verifies that val1==val2.
> Does pointer equality on pointers. If used on two C strings, it tests if they are in the same memory location, not if they have the same value. Use EXPECT_STREQ to compare C strings (e.g. const char*) by value.
>
> When comparing a pointer to NULL, use EXPECT_EQ(ptr, nullptr) instead of EXPECT_EQ(ptr, NULL).